# Сортировка ORDER BY по арифметическому выражению с участием нескольких полей

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать сортировку по рейтингу. Необходимо что бы MySQL условие `ORDER BY` брало поле с оценками делило его на поле с количеством голосовавших.

Возможно ли поставить такое условие? Как будет выглядеть такая конструкция?

Comment: А да все оказалось просто просто как я и написал нужно написать условие ORDER BY первое поле / второе поле

Comment: Так как мало кто чего понял из вопроса и вы сами уже нашли то, что искали - может проще удалить вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Для составления такого запроса вы можете использовать выражения после конструкции `ORDER BY`, например

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  marks / total DESC
```

Если поле `total` может принимать значение 0, тогда для того чтобы избежать деление на ноль, можно добавить условный выбор при помощи функции `IF()`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  IF(total = 0, 0, marks / total) DESC
```